# Button is not moving when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, position

I created a button that must *move to a random position* when it is clicked.
I created a html page with a button that has a
function.
The function is called and I created two variables *height* and *width* to generate a random height and width . But the **document.style.top** property is not working as expected . Please help me with a proper solution.
Thanks

The html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Move Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="Script.js" type="text/Javascript"> </script>
    <button id="my-button" onclick= "MoveText()" >Click me</button>


    <style>
        body {
             background-color: rgb(62, 59, 229);
             color:yellow;
             font-weight: 500;
             letter-spacing: 2;
             font-size: 35px;
             
         }
     </style>
 
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file (Script.js) :

```
function MoveText() {    
    const Button_select=document.getElementById('my-button')
    console.log(Button_select)

    var height=String(Math.floor(Math.random()*500))+'px'
    var width=String(Math.floor(Math.random()*900))+'px'

    Button_select.style.top = height;
    Button_select.style.left = width;


    Button_select.style.color = 'Red'
}
```

I also tried inline Javascript but didn't work.
I also added position property in the style section and tried setting it to absolute and relative but it didn't work.
I expect the button to appear in a random position when clicked.

Comment: if the CSS `position` of the button is the default, then top/left don't do anything ... you may want to change the `position` to something that CAN be moved

Comment: change the position of #my-button to absolute or relative

Comment: @AfzalK. relative could be awful if you know how relative works :p

Comment: Thank you for your help !! But can you explain why I should be doing so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your button is not positioned correctly. You need to position it fixed or absolute (relative to some parent element) for top/bottom/left/right css properties to work.

Change your HTML button code to

```
<button id="my-button" style="position: fixed;" onclick= "MoveText()" >Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS position of the button to a value other than static (default).

```js
Button_select.style.position = 'fixed';
```

Comment: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/pauL5ekx/)

Comment: I tried every possible values for the position property . But it still doesn't work . DId I left siomething or there was any typo ?

Comment: @AbishekB Did you try running the code in the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/pauL5ekx/) provided above? It works fine there.

Comment: It works fine thank you but I need the button to change its position , whenever the button is clicked . Also it moves to a specific position only and not to a random position in the screen . The above example only works once I guess. Also can you please explain me how the above Working example works ..

Comment: @AbishekB That's not true; it does move to a random position on each click in the JSFiddle.